# Why was the accept rate feature removed from a user's profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

In the past, users were afraid to have a low accept rate and actually bothered to accept an answer. Now most newbies don't!

Comment: probably because of effort put into asking this... 2 sentences? I mean come on.

Comment: @vba4all I can't believe that a well formed genuine question would get 4 down votes just because it is 2 sentences! Should I add a picture to make it pretty?

Comment: maybe your search that led you to asking?

Comment: Not really it was an observation I made

Comment: but the general rule of thumb on SE sites is [search and research before asking](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=accepted%20rate%20%2B%20stackexchange)... something you seem to have missed in your post.

Comment: But there's no other post that answers this question....

Comment: [oh, really?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Comment: Wowwww my bad then did not see that post

Comment: That question used to be here, but then the great meta split of 2013 and the land was smote and nobody checks for cross-site dupes and there was a great gnashing of teeth...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here on Stack Exchange, our focus is on **the questions** rather than the people asking them. Accordingly, an "acceptance percentage" put too much emphasis on the *user*, which caused some legitimate questions to go unanswered, so it was removed.

If you're looking at a user's statistics to decide whether answering a question is worth the effort, then you're doing what Stack Exchange is trying to prevent, and you should take another look at the question itself to decide its value.

---

As Mysticial [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272889/why-was-the-answer-rate-feature-removed-from-a-users-profile/272890?noredirect=1#comment101886_272890), however, another (possibly more realistic) reason for its removal was

> all the accept rate comment flags it generated.

That is, flags on comments that encourage askers to "get [their] accept rate up so that more people will answer [their] questions."

---

One of our resident moderators, animuson, [explains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272889/why-was-the-answer-rate-feature-removed-from-a-users-profile/272890?noredirect=1#comment101891_272890) that it was also just annoying to see people obsessing over a useless number and not answering questions for bad reasons. It encouraged askers to arbitrarily accept answers that didn't actually help them just to increase their percentage.

Comment: The *real* reason they took it out was because of all the accept rate comment flags it generated. And this whole thing about, "it's the content, not the user", is a bit of a PR excuse. If SE *really* wanted it to be 100% about the content and not the user, they wouldn't be showing user flairs on posts.

Comment: @Mysticial That's a fair point (I wasn't actually here when the rate was in use, so I just took this from what I've heard on other posts).

Comment: It wasn't solely because of the flags it generated, and not even so much because of the *comments themselves* that were generated. People were obsessed with a useless number and it was incredibly irritating. It not only stopped people from answering legitimate questions that could help *other people* rather than just the OP, but it also encouraged users to go around accepting potentially useless answers just to have a higher percentage and potentially get more questions answered. It was very damaging to the site in many different ways.

Comment: I understand all these reasons, and so I reckon the removal of the accept rate was a good idea, but still, something should still be done with some people, for example this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/1532494/kirpi4 who has posted a number of questions over the years, but the last time he accepted or upvoted any answer was in 2013.  (I don't know, perhaps send him a letter? or a thug to knock on his door? something anyway.)

Comment: I read this as, "Forget the guys that actually add real value to our site - we're more interested in pandering to the feelings of Joe Bloggs who couldn't be bothered to lift a finger to reward those who create real value for themselves and others, and allow our business to thrive." That's pretty awesome thinking right there. By all means, continue to encourage a slack and lethargic attitude.