# Should there be a beware rating?

Tags: feature-request, questions, users

A type of rating where the higher it is in the red, the more you think twice before helping someone out because they ask questions and then chronically abandon their posts after they have been solved?

Comment: Some sort of … Accept Rate %, perchance? (Hint: we had one. We dropped it because of some fatal flaws.)

Comment: There's no requirement that a user accept an answer to their question, so there's nothing to *rate*.

Comment: Doesnt have to be a requirement, but if it became visible for all users to see your habits, maybe it would change some other peoples behaviour around you

Comment: Don't worry about the accepted check mark.  If it is a good answer, it will get upvotes in time.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272889/62576) will explain why this is a bad idea. As @Nathan said, it's been tried before, and failed miserably for many reasons. Once again, it's not against any rules or policies *not* to accept an answer to your question here. There is no obligation to do so and no stigma attached for not accepting. If the only reason you're helping people here is to get a green check or reputation, you're here for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Like that would stop anyone from answering questions anyways :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I am legitimately having flashbacks to a more horrible time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=accept-rate) A time when people would leave the *stupidest* remark based on a person's accept rate.  A time when people wouldn't bother looking at questions posted by users that had an accept rate that wasn't favorable to them because it meant less chance for free Internet points.

I ***do not*** want to go back to that time.  I won't accept it.

---

To a more serious (and more lighthearted) side, perhaps you're missing the forest for the trees here.  Yes, an answer that's accepted nets you 15 whole rep and your question goes to the top of the list in certain sorting orders, but if the *community* feels like your answer is good, you'll get reputation from that; all it takes is two to exceed whatever bonus you were going to get from the accept anyway.*

Remember that you're not just answering their question, you're answering a question for everyone that happens upon it.  That's what's more important and key here.

Now, if the question is legitimately abandoned; that is, the OP hasn't made any clarifications as to what it is they're *asking*, just flag for closure and let the system handle it.  There's no sense in fretting over questions that people can't be bothered to spruce up a bit.

<sup>Yes, accepted answers are immune from the rep cap, but that's besides the point; if you were cruising on that anyway, you wouldn't worry about this.</sup>

Comment: The first link is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accept-rate?sort=votes, for those not using new-nav.