# Is pointing out OP's accept ratio in comments inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Is it inappropriate to point out that the OP has not accepted answers on all his/her previous questions?

I posted that as a comment to a user who only had 50% accept ratio. Of the 12 question asked only 6 of them had an answer accepted.
I didn't read every single answer and question but I scrolled through them and the top answer had a few upvotes on all of them if I recall correctly.

My comment was deleted within a few minutes. Is there anything wrong with saying accept your previous questions, and/or "warn" others who are about to answer this question.

Comment: The "official" accept rate stat was [removed partially because of comments like this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272889/why-was-the-accept-rate-feature-removed-from-a-users-profile and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361563/is-there-a-penalty-for-asking-too-many-questions-without-accepting-answers/361565#361565 (None of these are duplicates, just highly related.)

Comment: @Maroun I am guessing downvoters do not agree with Op's action..though I havent voted on it

Comment: @SurajRao There's no opinion here, only a question.

Comment: Why should it make a difference for people who answer whether op accepts answers or not? Writing answers that are helpful to a lot of people should be the main goal. If you only write answers for the rep, then this might burn you out very fast.

Comment: Hmmm ... I thought that on meta an upvote / downvote means I agree / disagree with the idea proposed by the question.  In this case, I read the question as proposing that it is not inappropriate ...

Comment: The odd thing is that I have seen the same thing be done several times in the past (a few months ago) and it has not been deleted. It actually got upvoted (the comment). But then again they had more rep points than me. Guess I need to work on that.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed, you do need t work on flagging such inappropriate comments in the future when you see them.  Just because one person does a thing doesn't mean it's automatically okay.

Comment: your comment probably contained word "acc*pt" which is one of those words that trigger [comments flags to have immediate effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601). See also: [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/839601)

Comment: Please improve your Meta accept-rate, it is way too low ...

Comment: @rene In meta I actually don't understand the accept button. The upvotes should be the deciding factor. I could potentially write an answer saying it's mandatory to accept answers and my answer should always be accepted whatever it is. Then accept it as the correct. Does that make it correct? Accepting on meta is in my opinion of no value.

Comment: @gnat I see didn't know about the auto triggers. Thanks!

Comment: @BDL my main goal of writing answers is to get better at programming. Some questions are more challenging than others and more rewarding (experience wise).

Comment: @Andreas If that's your goal then why are you harassing people for not accepting answers to all of their questions?

Comment: @Servy harassing.. right... So one comment is harassing? Where is that flag button? Your harassing me.

Comment: @Andreas I'll take that as meaning you don't have any reason for it then.

Answer (score 22):

This is both wrong in that it's badgering and *could* mislead users, and also entirely pointless.

Accepting an answer is ***100% optional and up to the OP's discretion.*** You don't know why they didn't accept answers on those other posts. Maybe they didn't feel any of the answers deserved to be accepted. Maybe there was more than one answer, and the OP couldn't decide which to accept.

We have no right to *demand* the OP accept an answer- We don't get to decide when they feel an answer deserves to be accepted. And, as I said, it's entirely optional and not mandatory to accept answers. From the [help center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

In other words, comments like these are unnecessary, noisy, and should be flagged as "no longer needed" if you see them from someone else. No one has to accept an answer on every question they ask.

Comment: It is also wrong, as badgering people to accept answers can lead to incorrect answers being accepted by new-ish users, that might have gotten the impression that accepting is somehow mandatory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't consider that, edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is extremely simple: **Nope.**

Please do not solicit for accept checkmarks or upvotes. That is completely up to the asker's choice, period. Comments that solicit checkmarks or upvotes such as "This answer is great, accept it" are no longer needed, noisy, and are liable to flags.

Also, the asker can remove accept checkmarks at any time, causing a -15 unaccept reputation change.

Comment: "Never" is, as ever, too strong a word. I think it's okay once: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/458741