# Should I tell someone to accept answers to their questions

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, users

Should I encourage users to go through their history and see if they feel that some of their questions received answers worth marking accepted if they have a history of asking questions, and many of those questions have multiple answers, and the OP has even acknowledged in comments that an answer solved their problem, but they have never marked an answer as accepted before.

---

So now that I know that so many folks hold such negative opinions about accepted answers, why not remove them altogether?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Accepted answers are often of questionable value.

Comment: @user4581301 That is absolutely true. But I still think that it discourages people from wanting to help someone if they think there is little chance of receiving a bump in reputation for their effort

Comment: "*Also having a history of never marking questions as answered can discourage users from wanting to assist you.*" => Yep, completely true for me, I ***always*** check their "History" and previous Threads/Qt's for Users asking Qt's in the (small) Thread I answer and if I notice a "poor" Trail of poor Follow-up and no Answer  Acceptance for all of them, I then post a Comment saying they "would first need to follow up and finish their previous Threads "a bit correctly"" for me to *eventually* be "motivated" to answer their Qt...

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to badger people for their accept rates, and threaten no answers if they don't accept stuff? Most people don't care about accept rates. Moreover, the comments are still classified as noise, and will be deleted when noticed or flagged, even if they're not warnable or suspendable thanks to a meta proposal that got steamrolled

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine So your saying that you think visitors get no value ever from accepted answers?  And that most people using this site don't mind putting their effort into answering a question that is never acknowledged and are never rewarded for their effort?

Comment: We have plenty of high-quality, unaccepted answers that most certainly do get rewarded. One single +15 is not worth badgering users over, particularly when upvotes for actually good answers easily outscale accepts. Badgering users also usually doesn't do much to help with accept rates. All it does is add more comment noise, and risks leaving a threat around for everyone to see; that doesn't foster a healthy community, that just breeds one based on more stress and hate around voting. That's by absolutely no metric helpful to the community, or anyone else.

Comment: Related: [Teaching new users how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354584/2745495) (That question is specifically for "new users", but contains the links to other related requests/discussions on asking people mark answers as accepted. The same arguments and answers apply.)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine That is awfully big of you to be so above a +15, But I think most people like to have their effort acknowledged and there are plenty of good answers that never get acknowledged because of a poorly titled question or some other extremely common reason.

Comment: @Alexander It's not about being "above a +15", it's being above threatening users into giving a +15 for what's mostly a dopamine hit. Yes, the UI should have better onboarding, including into voting, but bringing people's voting history into play is an excellent way to trigger responses that just push people away in the end. This is also why accept rates were removed; [it was actively damaging to the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272889/why-was-the-accept-rate-feature-removed-from-a-users-profile/272890#comment101891_272890) in several ways

Comment: The point isn't "+15 pointless", it's "don't generate noise because of +15", where the noise also happens to be pointless, and new users take it poorly. This is regardless of how nicely you phrase it. It coming from an individual alone increases the probability it's received poorly. If you're looking to push away users, by all means, post your comment. But it isn't in the best interest of the community. It's not even remotely constructive for the community at large

Comment: "*And that most people using this site don't mind putting their effort into answering a question that is never acknowledged and are never rewarded for their effort?*" that's what upvotes are for.

Comment: *"good answers that never get acknowledged because of a poorly titled question"* This is an _excellent_ reason to touch up the questions you answer to make them better and easier to find. In fact, we have the [Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer)/[Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner)/[Illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badge series to encourage exactly this.  Answers are only really useful if other people can find them, after all.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine  You seem to really be caught up on interpreting the last sentence as some kind of threat so I removed it.

Comment: "So now that I know that so many folks hold such negative opinions about accepted answers, why not remove them altogether?" My best guess is that there are enough people who want the +15 to prevent any consensus to remove it.

Comment: @Alexander You've still missed the "This is regardless of how nicely you phrase it" part. You're still pointing out that you took the time to review their accept history, causing a sense of pressure, which can and will cause damage

Comment: I noticed you only marked one of your previous question posts as having an answer that you found to be acceptable, and I just thought I should remind you that while it isn't a requirement it would be great if you could remember to do that. It is helpful to the community as a whole when a question is marked as having an answer that worked for the OP and it also encourages users to want to help you and other MSO users in the future when their efforts are acknowledged.

Comment: “I am hoping to get some feedback and suggestions on a short, polite, but clear message to users to participate in marking their own questions as answered.” - There isn’t a way. Once you have answered the question it’s inappropriate to ask the author of a question to accept your answer. That type of comment will be instantly flagged by this user

Comment: @SecurityHound  You misread the question thanks for the feedback tho

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine  I really didn't you have made your position perfectly clear.  I was simply stating that I removed the part that you were referring to as a threat... Thanks for the feedback tho

Comment: @Alexander - No, I quoted your own words.  **I didn't misread anything**

Comment: @SecurityHound  I never said that I was asking them to mark my own answer. That part you did not quote and I am assuming you misread because the alternative is that you just made it up

Answer (score 7):

> The appropriate way to tell someone to assign answers to their questions

Don't.

Whether or not somebody has accepted any answers is, quite frankly, none of your business. And I do not even know why you think it is. It seriously comes off as pushy and overbearing.

The none-of-your-business aspect is reinforced by the fact that acceptance rate *used to be* a statistic kept for users *but has been removed since*. It simply does not lead to anything productive.

I would even argue that accepted answers themselves are useless. Because the site's purpose is to house Q&A. The ability of *one* person to accept an answer has, historically, produced more problems than not.

[image: Comic satirising the voting system on Stack Overflow. Title is "The story of the StackOverflow electoral system or how a checkmark reduces the code quality around the world". It represents two answers - one of low quality with a score of 2 but accepted and on top, many people using it. The other answer with a score of 42, on second place and barely any users.]

Comment: And we now have different sorting options. Hopefully the cream will once again rise to the top. It's too late for some answers that have been voted for less than the inferior answer previously pinned to the top by the checkmark for perhaps a decade, but there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: The comic seems wrong. If the pinned-to-the-top answer were really getting that much use, wouldn't it also start getting a bunch of upvotes? (It's not wrong in the main, that pinning a low-quality answer to the top is harmful, but pointing out why things are correct is not my hobby.)

Comment: @CodyGray No, because the vast majority of people who use the site either don't have an account, or don't have an account with vote privileges. The vote:view ratio often shrinks substantially as views go up as a consequence of that

Comment: Oh, and the unregistered users, and users without voting privs often pick the first answer indiscriminately. If it's at the top and has a green checkmark, "that must work". high-rep users do that too, to be fair, but we lack data points for users who can't vote, and who copy the top answer regardless of real quality. It's part of the unavoidable bias the vote system, and particularly the accept system introduces.

Comment: @VLAZ Well seeing as you think I am a creep for even considering it. Would you mind removing your answer, so I can delete my question altogether?  Or at least editing your response so it isn't so insulting?

Comment: @Alexander VLAZ said the action was creepy, not that you're a creep. That's a _very_ important distinction. It's perfectly possible to do something creepy, or dumb, or any other adjective, without yourself having those traits as an individual. The answer points out what your actions come across as, not what you necessarily are. That isn't an insult

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine  I still find it insulting, and I don't think my request is unreasonable.  Obviously they can choose to ignore it if they want to.